# PHP syntax error unexpected ','?

Tags: php

The "syntax error unexpected ','" error is occurring here:

```
$foo1 = ($foo2, true);
```

Is the comma not suppose to be there?

Comment: Yep. You probably mean something like `foo($foo2, true);`, the function name being the difference. ;)

Comment: what are you trying to do there ? usualy you use () for math , passing function arguments arrays or whatever but you're not doing any of those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are either trying to create an array:

```
$foo1 = array($foo2, true);
```

Or calling a function:

```
$foo1 = myFunc($foo2, true);
```

Or trying to use a [C comma expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which PHP does not support (then again in that case `$foo1` would just be assigned to `true`).

Comment: btw, array() is also function :)

Comment: @heximal: No, it's a language construct. The manual lists it as a function only because it does the same for `include`, `require`, `echo`, `print`, etc, which are all language constructs. Syntactically you can call them like functions, but they're not.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid php expression.

```
$foo =myfunc($foo2, true);
```

Will call the **function** myfunc with the parameters $foo2 and true. The result will then be assigned to $foo.

```
$foo = array($foo2, true);
```

Will create a new **array** with two elements($foo2 and true)

```
$foo = ($foo2, true);
```

Will just throw a parse error because  the only valid symbols between to variables in this context are operators(+,-,%,AND,...).